# Using PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory for multi-word synonyms

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm trying to get synonyms to work on terms that have whitespace which apparently is a shortcoming of solr. To hack it, I'm trying to use PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory to replace whitespace with hyphens and then hyphenate my synonyms:

```
<fieldType name="special_synonyms" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="100" />
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
          generateWordParts="1"
          generateNumberParts="1"
          catenateWords="1"
          catenateNumbers="1"
          catenateAll="0"
          preserveOriginal="1"
  />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([/\s+])" replacement="-" />
  <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
</analyzer>
```

Using the Analysis tool I get the correct synonyms when I enter my multi-word term, but when I run a query it finds 0 results unless I manually add the hyphen myself.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcoming of Solr is that the space-parsing happens **before** the analyzer is invoked. Therefore your hack should not work. This is in process of being fixed, but is not yet ready. The issue to watch is [SOLR-9185](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9185)

Try sending your query as a phrase ("quoted string"). Or use [Field Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-FieldQueryParser) with your text sent through a local parameter variable.

Or you may be interested in trying a free 3rd-party [Match Query Parser](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2017/01/23/our-solution-to-solr-multiterm-synonyms/).